# Objective-C Bridging Header Not Working for Swift File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to migrate my project to Swift, and started by making an Objective-C Bridger File filled with #imports to relevant .h files. I've checked exhaustively that the Build Settings options and path are correct. I created a Swift file for a UITableViewController that looks something like this:

**TableViewController.swift**

```
class TableViewController {
    var title: String = ""
    var summary: String = ""

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = UIResources.getString(settingsKey, withSuffix: "title")
        summary = UIResources.getString(settingKey, withSuffix: "summary")
    } 

    ...

}
```

However, every line starting with the first override result in errors like

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

and

> 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class

I'm pretty unfamiliar with working with Objective-C, so I'm not sure what I need to change, if anything. Here is the .h file of the class I imported in the bridging header also. I'm really stumped on this one.

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TableViewController

@protocol TableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) tableViewControllerDidSave: (UIViewController *)controller forKey:(NSString *)key withNewValue:(id) value;

@end

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <TableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *settingKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id stringValue;

@end
```

Comment: You should take a look at `@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController` and see what you could do differently in Swift `class TableViewController`. Hint: Your class should be a subclass.

Comment: Right, I figured it out by adding the delegate code above the class and adding the variables to the TableVC class. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an update to your question including the result(as an answer to future readers)?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I needed to add the type to the class definition

```
class TableViewController : UITableViewController, TableViewControllerDelegate {
```

That's what you get when you blind trust [objectivec2swift.com](http://objectivec2swift.com) :P

I also added the variables and protocol outlined in the .h file to the Swift file.